# Airplane mode activates sporadically

Tags: 18.04, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on a Lenovo thinkpad. Every few minutes it toggles airplane mode without any input from me.

I thought the problem might be a hardware fault with the airplane mode shortcut <kbd>Fn + F8</kbd>, but I see no output from

```
sudo evtest /dev/input/event3
```

when it happens (whereas I do see output when pressing the key myself).

I added a `udev` rule on `SUBSYSTEM=="rfkill"` to capture the parent process chain and environment variables. An example event:

```
/sbin/init splash -> /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd -> /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
ACTION=change
USEC_INITIALIZED=40256953
ID_PATH_TAG=pci-<...>
SUBSYSTEM=rfkill
SEQNUM=3704
DEVPATH=/devices/<...>/phy0/rfkill2
PWD=/
SYSTEMD_RFKILL=1
RFKILL_STATE=0
RFKILL_NAME=phy0
ID_PATH=pci-<...>
SHLVL=1
RFKILL_TYPE=wlan
_=/usr/bin/env
```

It looks there are 3 events each time it happens, namely change wifi, change bluetooth and add/remove bluetooth.

Although I am interested in the root cause, my primary question is **how to work around the issue to have an uninterrupted wifi connection?** I don't mind losing the shortcut functionality, or needing to run a script to toggle airplane mode.